How do I pay and book an appointment for a C1D visa in the UAE? The US visa docs are not showing UAE in the countries list
I'm a Kenyan citizen applying for a C1D visa in the UAE. On the USA travel  docs I can't create an account because it's showing different countries but not the UAE, and I'm applying from there.

In the UAE, USTravelDocs is not the website you need to use
The embassy of the United States in Abu Dhabi links to AIS which is the processor of visa applications in the UAE
